# Comparison with empty set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two relations A and B

Table A

```
Name   Age
------------
Arun    60 
Shreya  24 
Rohit   11
```

Table B

```
Name    Age
------------
Hari     40
Rohit    20
Karthik  18

select *
from A
where A.Age > all(select B.Age from B where B.Name = 'Arun');
```

I know that the sub-query would return an empty set. I come to know that the `all()` would consider NULL value if there is an empty set. In that case, the predicate in the where clause of the outer query should evaluate to UNKNOWN, thereby eliminating all the tuples returned by from clause.

But, the query is returning all tuples from relation A as output.

Please explain how the all() function is handling the empty set.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please tag your questions only with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ALL` is doing exactly what it says.  It is comparing `A.age` to every value returned by the query.  The filter passes if `A.age` is larger than all the values of `B.age`.

There are no values, so this is true.

You are confusing an empty result set with a result set that has a row with `NULL`.  These are different things.

Incidentally, I usually write this logic as:

```
select *
from A
where A.Age > (select max(B.Age) from B where B.Name = 'Arun');
```

In this case, the comparison is not to a set; the comparison is to a scalar value.  And, the scalar value is `NULL` because the subquery returns no rows.  So, this returns no rows in this situation.  The results are the same when your subquery returns any rows.